# Are the forks in fixed places in the philosopher dinner?

Tags: algorithm, dining-philosopher

The philosophers dinner is a classic concurrency problem. See description [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem).
In the [Conductors solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem#Conductor_solution) are the forks put back in specific places or just put into a general heap.  So will the left fork for any philosopher be the same left fork? Or can it be a different fork as the evening progresses?

Comment: As far as I understand the forks have no fixed place and will be return to a general heap. The waiter just oversees how many forks are in play and will control access to this heap of forks.

Comment: @benst I see it's like connection pooling then.

Comment: Ok i am confused now as well. I always thought the waiter to be like this. 4 forks are in play so if someone wants to pick up a fork he is denied untill another person releases a fork. If the forks are always the same or are thrown in a pile this would not make a difference. Because the waiter will deny a fork to be handed out to a person who does not have a fork already in case that 4 forks have been handed out /picked up. Am I making any sense here?

Comment: In essence I think this excersise assumes that the forks will be places at the same position again after releasing.

Comment: @benst If the forks are not going back to the same place I don't see the significance of them all seating around together at a table.  They would be as disconnected from that as the forks. But I open to correction.

Comment: The essence remains the same if we have 5 forks and need 2 to eat then we have a deadlock if everyone picks up 1 fork. But of course to keep the table anology going the will be put back in the same place. I am not the smartest guy on stackoverflow so it might be nice if someone else commented as well.

Comment: Hey anyone smart out there?